# Finite loop in .bat files

Tags: loops, batch-file

I am working with Notepad++ and am trying to make an finite loop in .bat without having to write the same command over and over again. i'm working on a formula that goes

```
set x=0 
:A 
set y=1 

echo %random% %random%%random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random%

set Z=%x%+%y% 
goto :A until %Z% = 50
```

... but every time that it goes back to `:A`, `Z` doesn't maintain the value that it has gained.. is there a way I can make a linear growth until `Z=50`?

Comment: What website or help file were you reading that said Windows Batch files have an `UNTIL` command?

Comment: Type `for /?` at a command-prompt and look at the `/L` option.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are attempting to do.

```
@Echo off

set Z=1 
:A 

echo %random% %random%%random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random%

set /A Z+=1 
IF NOT "%Z%"=="50" goto :A
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

...and using `For /L` as mentioned in the comments:

```
Set "start=1"
Set "step=1"
Set "end=50"

For /L %%A In (%start%,%step%,%end%) Do (
    Echo %random% %random%%random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random%
)
```

Comment: I like that much better!